# How to create a clear icons in selectfield and datepicker with sencha touch 2.1.0?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

By default,the clear icon is usually used in a text input,while in some occasion,the user wants to reset the selected item or the picked date to empty things if there are many optional select fields or datepickers in the viewport. 
The selectfield will always make you select a non-empty item even you have touched the select area by mistake!
How can do this ? Or i just add an button next to the selectfield showing 'clear' which will reset the selected value in the selectfield to placeholder or to an empty thing when tapped on ?

Comment: I didn't really understand that, can we get some screenshots or code?

Comment: @pfrank I just want to add a clear icon in the selectfield or datepicker so that the user could restore the selected item to the place holder.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a button or image next to the picker that you are trying to clear, and then have a listener that clears the component. You can style it to look like the clear icon. Something like this http://www.senchafiddle.com/#JKrEf